# Which status code/error message to use if implied resource not found

Tags: rest

Let's say I have an endpoint `/process` which accepts a POST request with an `object_id`. My API, however, needs to access several children of the object with id `object_id` to work out its response.

Assuming the object is found but the children aren't, which status code and error message should I return?

Since I want to inform the end user that something went wrong as opposed to returning a blank response, I can see several options:

- `400 Bad Request`. However, this could wrongly imply there is something wrong with the request, which there isn't.
- `404 Not Found`. However, this could wrongly imply that the object referenced by `object_id` does not exist, which it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard HTTP status code for this scenario. `4xx` codes imply a *client error*, whereas `5xx` is for *server errors*. Arguably there is nothing wrong with the request in this case, so you could return a custom `5xx` status code.

Some standard status codes however come close:

- `409 Conflict`
- `422 Unprocessable Entity`
- and even `404 Not Found`

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to determine whether the problem is client-side or server-side.
4XX errors are for bad requests. Implying that there is something wrong with the request sent from the user.
If not finding the object is due to server-side issues, I think it's better to throw a server-side error (i.e. 5XX).

## Update:

Following a comment from OP, my suggestion is: `412 (Precondition Failed)`. Also, I think Not-Found and No-Content statuses don't fit your scenario.

Comment: The problem is client-side because the request implies that certain resources exist which haven't been created yet (i.e. by the client)

Comment: In this case, 412 (Precondition Failed) can be a good status.

Comment: `412` is for when preconditions like `If-Modified-Since`, `If-Match`, etc. were present